# devtools will not show the changes on less files modification

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am trying to use devTools to modify local less file and sourceMaps to directly see the result in the page.

I've used bootstrap and the provided less files and the map file as well. I didn't modify anything to be sure that my first testing file wasn't compromising anything.

I am using the last build of the chrome browser. I have set the workspace in devTools as to made possible the edition of the source files, as well as I've checked the option allowing devTools to use sourcemap and auto-reload changing css.

When I load my page and inspect an element, the less file link is well showned in the css inspector.

[image]

However when i edit the less file directly in the devTools and save, nothing happened. the content's appearance should change.

Do you have some suggestions ? something i may do wrong ?

Comment: Chrome does not compile those Less files you edit so the CSS used in the page does not change (you need to use some watchers, e.g. the most common recommendation is `Grunt`/`Gulp`).

Comment: @seven-phases-max yes I am using watchers for now, but i have seen tutorials on the web, devtools seems to comprehend the compilation of less file. Is this feature removed from chrome ? if yes, from which intentions ?

Comment: No, Chrome never was able to compile Less files on its own. (Probably what you read was something about [Client-Side compilation](http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser) but that's another story).

Comment: @seven-phases-max I am not using any drugs.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6bcCpk_U3qc

Comment: In the video it's not Chrome that compiles Less files but the framework this guy is demonstrating invokes `lessc` (basically it's just the same method as with `Grunt`/`Gulp` watchers just using another framework instead).

Comment: (strictly speaking, as you can read in the video description, it's note even a framework but the [`nodemon` tool](http://nodemon.io/) and a `node` server).

Comment: @seven-phases-max ok now I get the picture. And could manage to make it worked using this method. thanks for your help m8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally understood that devtools is not processing less files but rather refreshes the page whenever the less files are being modified externally.

Technically the less files are being watched by a program (e.g. grunt-contrib-watch module) and when they are modified the compilation is generating the stylesheet again which is spied by devtools and consequently refreshes the page.

The modification of the less files themselves in devtools is made possible by adding the less files in the devtools workspace.

More informations following the links :

**grunt-contrib-watch** : https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch

**devtools** : https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

**less** : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(stylesheet_language)